# python-sympy: lambdify returns the wrong answer when function defined piecewise

Tags: python, sympy, piecewise

I am baffled at why the answer to the following code is 10 and not 1. Can someone help me understand what is going on with `lambdify` or what is creating the wrong answer?

```
import sympy
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify
from sympy import Function
from sympy.abc import x, y

def kFct(xIndex,loc,k1,k2):
...   if xIndex <= loc:
...     return k1
...   else:
...     return k2
... 
loc = 0.5
k1 = 1
k2 = 10

kfun = lambdify( (x,y), kFct(x,loc,k1,k2) )
print kfun(0,0)
>>> 10
```

Why isn't the answer `k1` or 1, since `x = 0`, which is less than `loc = 0.5`?

However, it return the correct answer if I do

```
print kfct(0,loc,k1,k2)
>>> 1
```

I need to have `kfun` as a function of x and y, because later on, I use it as part of an argument for an integral. It will also eventually depend on y.

I'm using python 2.6.8 on a Mac 10.6.x.

Answer (score 3):

The arguments to `lambdify` are evaluated before they're passed, and so you're not actually passing your function to `lambdify`, you're passing the number 10:

```
>>> kFct(x, loc, k1, k2)
10
```

You get 10 here because

```
>>> x <= loc
x <= 0.5
>>> bool(x <= loc)
False
```

and so the second branch is taken.  Because of the way Python works, I don't think you'll be able to get this to work -- you can't suppress only one branch being taken.  (In principle, a program could do some crazy bytecode introspection, but I'm pretty sure `sympy` doesn't.)

You could use `implemented_function`, though:

```
>>> f = implemented_function(Function('kFct'), lambda x,y: kFct(x, loc, k1, k2))
>>> kfun = lambdify((x,y), f(x,y))
>>> kfun(0,0)
1
>>> kfun(0.5,0)
1
>>> kfun(0.51,0)
10
>>> kfun(1, 0.0)
10
```

I'm not sure how much this really benefits you, though, given the extra indirection: I'd probably just work with the function itself (assuming you're ultimately looking for a numerical evaluation of the integral.)

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `Piecewise`, which represents if branches in a symbolic way that SymPy can work with.

Here's your example with the values of `loc`, `k1`, and `k2` put in explicitly.  You can of course use them symbolically and replace them later with `subs` if your code dictates that.

```
>>> kFct = Piecewise((1, x < 0.5), (10, True))
>>> kfun = lambdify(x, kFct)
>>> kfun(0)
1
>>> kfun(1)
10
```